# How to get ChromOS to stop asking what client cert to use?

Tags: google-chrome-os, mtls

I have a setup using mutual TLS authentication (client certs) and it's working, but for some reason CrOS periodically prompts for which cert to use, even thought the user already answered that and there is only one cert that would work; the same one they selected last time.

How do I make CrOS continue to use a client-cert for as long as it is valid and works without further prompts?

---

Searches for variations on that theme results in a lot of hits but they mostly are for different problems or things I've already got working (e.g. "how to make it it work at all"). The few that look to me like they *might* be productive boil down to "what's the proper way to install certificates" ([e.g.](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6324985?hl=en)) and I'm only guessing that installing them a different (and more complicated for me) way might make a difference. And that high cost + low likelihood of success makes me reluctant to invest the effort to remove what is basically just a big eyesore.